# Change column count in bootstrap at different breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have been given a PSD with the following setup:
desktop - 10 columns
tablet - 8 columns
mobile - 4 columns

Each have the same gutter.

I am using bootstrap SASS, and have set up the 10 columns and gutter in variables. Is there a way to have the column count change at different breakpoints?

Using 40 columns would not work as the gutter spacing would be wrong

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: this is where stackoverflow can be quite infuriating sometimes. What code would it be useful to show? I am asking someone with good experience of boostrap if its possible to set different column counts at different breakpoints

Comment: Did you try something with provided grid classes of Bootstrap? Like `col-md-10`, `col-sm-8` and `col-xs-4`?

Comment: that would just create 10/10, 8/10 and 4/10 at different screen sizes